# Build using 0.5 libyaml-cpp-dev fails with boost errors

Tags: c++, cmake, yaml-cpp

I installed libyaml-cpp-dev via `sudo apt install libyaml-cpp-dev` and got yaml-cpp 0.5 version installed on my machine.

```
dpkg -s libyaml-cpp-dev | grep Version
Version: 0.5.2-4ubuntu1
```

Using this , I tried to build a testing code, demo.cpp as below:

```
#include <string>
#include "yaml-cpp/yaml.h"

int main(){
  std::string config_file{"/home/freyr/exper/yamp-cpp/rvs.conf"};
  YAML::Node config = YAML::LoadFile(config_file);
  return 0;
}
```

with a cmake,

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8.11)
project (HELLO)
find_package(yaml-cpp REQUIRED)
add_executable (helloDemo demo.cpp)
include_directories(${YAML_CPP_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(helloDemo ${YAML_CPP_LIBRARIES})
```

When I tried to build , I get below error:

```
make: Entering directory '/home/freyr/exper/yamp-cpp/build' make[1]: Entering directory '/home/freyr/exper/yamp-cpp/build' make[2]: Entering directory '/home/freyr/exper/yamp-cpp/build' Scanning dependencies of target helloDemo make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/freyr/exper/yamp-cpp/build' make[2]: Entering directory '/home/freyr/exper/yamp-cpp/build' [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/helloDemo.dir/demo.cpp.o In file included from /usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/iterator.h:13:0,
                 from /usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/impl.h:11,
                 from /usr/include/yaml-cpp/yaml.h:17,
                 from /home/freyr/exper/yamp-cpp/demo.cpp:3: /usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/iterator.h: In member function ‘void YAML::detail::iterator_base<V>::increment()’: /usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/iterator.h:48:54: error: ‘next’ is not a member of ‘boost’    void increment() { this->base_reference() = boost::next(this->base()); }
                                                      ^~~~ /usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/iterator.h:48:54: note: suggested alternatives: In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:66:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:39,
                 from /home/freyr/exper/yamp-cpp/demo.cpp:1: /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h:208:5: note:   ‘std::next’
     next(_ForwardIterator __x, typename
     ^~~~ In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/mpl/next.hpp:17:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/mpl/bind.hpp:25,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/mpl/lambda.hpp:18,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/mpl/apply.hpp:25,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp:36,
                 from /usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_iterator.h:12,
                 from /usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/iterator.h:12,
                 from /usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/iterator.h:13,
                 from /usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/impl.h:11,
                 from /usr/include/yaml-cpp/yaml.h:17,
                 from /home/freyr/exper/yamp-cpp/demo.cpp:3: /usr/local/include/boost/mpl/next_prior.hpp:29:8: note:   ‘boost::mpl::next’  struct next
        ^~~~ CMakeFiles/helloDemo.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/helloDemo.dir/demo.cpp.o' failed make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/helloDemo.dir/demo.cpp.o] Error 1 make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/freyr/exper/yamp-cpp/build' CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/helloDemo.dir/all' failed make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/helloDemo.dir/all] Error 2 make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/freyr/exper/yamp-cpp/build' Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I see in latest https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/blob/master/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/iterator.h there are no references to boost ad it is all std c++ alone.
How do I install latest version of libyaml-cpp-dev which has no boost dependencies ? I dont want to build and install from latest version as git cloning from master every time will not be a very secure practice.

Answer (score 0):

yaml-cpp introduced boost dependency in version 0.5 and removed it in version 0.6. You need to upgrade your Ubuntu to a newer release or install yaml-cpp from sources, or install  a  version of yaml-cpp older than 0.5.

See: https://yaml-cpp.docsforge.com/#how-to-build

> yaml-cpp 0.6.0 has been released! This release requires C++11, and no longer depends on Boost.

See also https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/hirsute/main/base/yaml-cpp - the current version of yaml-cpp in Ubuntu 21.4 is 0.6.3-9ubuntu1

Comment: Installing yaml-cpp from sources is not possible in certain air-gapped setups which cannot clone from yaml sources. I am using Ubuntu 18.04, for which apt gets me libyaml-0.5 which sadly has boost dependencies. I was looking for a way to specify versions using which latest package gets installed. None of the appendings like libyaml-cpp-dev0.6 or libyaml-cpp-dev0.6.3-10 work.

Comment: Ubuntu should have a possibility to  install (downgrade to) older packages, that is, 0.4.* or earlier.